# Get start index of selected text in entire html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to obtain the character(s) that come before the text that the user has highlighed, and i need to include html in this. When the example below is rendered, the user will only see "word". When a user highlights this i want to be able to figure out that there is an angle bracket (or any other char)

```
<span>word</span>
```

The following will give me the selection and it gives me a start and an end index, but these are relative to the node that this text belongs to. It is also dom related and doesn't include html.

```
selectedText= childwindow.getSelection();
```

To get around this i have tried to get the `indexOf` value for this piece of text on the html string of the page and this works.

```
childwindow.document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf(selectedText)
```

The issue with this is that if I highlight something like "the", a word that appears on the page several times, the index is not correct. I can understand why, but I dont know what else to do. I would imagine i need to get this from the dom somehow as this knows the exact piece of text that I have obtained.

Even if this is not possible, is there anything i can grab from the dom that will help me make the indexOf request more reliable. I can add extra data under the hood to make sure it matches the value I want.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do the trick:

```
function textSelected() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        t = window.getSelection().toString() || "";
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        t = document.selection.createRange().text || "";
    }
    return t;
}
```

Main thing is window's function `getSelection` which:

> Returns a Selection object representing the range of text selected by
>   the user or the current position of the caret.

Once you have it, just get what you wanna from Selection obj.

The else part is in case you have selected across elements. Then you need to use selection range. More on document.selection:
[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)